# Magento 2 calling External API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

How do I call an External API in Magento 2? And what file/folder do I do it in?

Comment: check this one , it might help you https://github.com/baddwin/magento2-ongkir/blob/master/Model/Query/Api.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
        $url = " "; //url External API
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); // or POST
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " .$token));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```